# How do I simulate a web session and store the received cookie using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing, single-sign-on

I am testing a messaging application that uses single sign-on(SSO).  I need to simulate a user connecting to WAM using SSO, then I need to get the cookie from the server and store it for further communication events.  Is anyone familiar with how this might be done using Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) does that automatically. There are also other [HTTP client gems](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients.html) that may support cookies, e.g. [this httparty example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/tripit_sign_in.rb).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention or need is to do this more 'organically' as it were, then you could use Watir to drive a browser, and retrieve the cookie (assuming it's stored on disk and not a session cookie) from wherever the browser stores it using normal file I/O functions.  If it's a session cookie that's a bit tricker but you can usually see them with developer tools like firebug.

If you want something operating at the HTTP level that is simulating a browser, then See the other answer provided by MichaelW